# How can I address my CORS issue from my hosted website which works on localhost?

Tags: python, angular

I have the following code which is working well from my localhost but, when I try to call the API from my website bowtieteacher.co.uk, I get an error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mathsapplication-mnfu5bhqyq-nw.a.run.app/predictions' from origin 'https://bowtieteacher.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polyfills.bb7759b4fc9d057e.js:1     POST https://mathsapplication-mnfu5bhqyq-nw.a.run.app/predictions net::ERR_FAILED

---

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from app.model.model import predict_grade
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


class DataIn(BaseModel):
    percentages: List[float]


class PredictionGrade(BaseModel):
    grade: int
    accuracy: float


origins = [
    'http://localhost:4200',
    'https://www.bowtieteacher.co.uk',
    'https://maths-7b24d.web.app',
]

middleware = [
    Middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=['*'],
        allow_headers=['*']
    )
]

app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {"health_check": "Health check"}


@app.post("/predictions", response_model=PredictionGrade)
def predict(payload: DataIn):
    result = predict_grade(payload.percentages)
    return {"grade": result[0], "accuracy": result[1]}
```

Could anybody please explain why it is working for my localhost and not my website? And if so, perhaps a suggestion as to what I could do for next steps? It works on Postman and I have researched answers but I don't understand what is wrong. I create a docker file from this code for my machine learning model which is hosted on Google Cloud if that helps.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Add `'https://bowtieteacher.co.uk',` to origins

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the Server has been configured to allow OPTIONS HTTP verb.

I'm from AWS background, but pretty sure GCP must have some mechanism to allow OPTIONS verb before the actual GET call or so.

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, POST, GET"; on the server config (something similar).

Also on the GCP Cloudfront parallel of AWS concept, the localhost making the request needs to be whitelisted.

Comment: allow_methods=['*'], would cover this.